# CI/CD stuck on NPM start process in Github Actions

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

My pipeline always gets stuck in the `run: npm run start` process and doesn't make it to the next job. My tests consist of API tests, so I need to keep the server running. What am I doing wrong?

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
       run:
         working-directory: ./backend/
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
        cache-dependency-path: './backend/package-lock.json'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run start
    - run: npm run test
```

my *package.json* scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

Comment: Add your package.json script and also check if it’s on nodemon

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril I added my package.json scripts

Comment: I don't think it'll work that way. You should be running your tests before `start` and within your `test` should start the server and do the API checks. I don't think you'll ever reach `test` because the app is started and unless your app terminates then how do you expect to it reach `test`?